How to change git author of a single class in big commit?
I have a commit in which some person deleted my class and added it to new package and as a result all lines are annotated by name of that person. I want to bring myself back so that people would contact with me about this class not with that person. In the commit there were multiple classes changed, added but only one was mine and should be mine again. How to do that with git ?

And the file was removed/added in the same commit or on separate commits?

Git blame is a sub-optimal tool to finding the correct contact at best. It's a second choice if no other source is available. If you need contact information, either provide it in the docs of the class (JavaDoc or similar, just a comment in the header for example) or create dedicated OWNERS files that list what each person is responsible for. But trying to "fix" git blame to show "who's really responsible" is a terrible idea, because normal code changes will "break" your system.

This is phrased in a confusing way. First you say that someone changed some classes but presumably it was really they who did it so they are the proper author. You just don’t want people to contact them (via git-blame(1)?). Then you say that one of the changes in the commit was yours but the rest wasn’t. Now you’re asking how to split a commit.

You can use git blame --ignore-revs-file <file> where <file> lists revisions/commits that git-blame(1) should ignore. That could be commits like code-move refactors.

Changing a commit's author
If it's the last commit on the history, you can change the author of the last commit:
git commit --amend --author="John Doe <john@doe.org>" --no-edit

If some other commits have been made since, you can use a rebase:

start an interactive rebase: git rebase -i <commit id>
change pick for "edit" for the commit you want to change the author, then save and quit the file. If you want to change the author of multiple commits, set "edit" for everyone of them.
git will rebase commit after commit, and will stop on the commit for which you said "edit". Amend this commit: git commit --amend --author="John Doe <john@doe.org>" --no-edit
continue the rebase: git rebase --continue. Git will continue rebasing commit after commit until the whole history has been rebased.

Note that this solution does not actually update the commit, it recreates it with a different author. After doing this, your local history and the history on your remote git repository will diverge, as you have a history with a commit that is not the same commit as the one in the repository. This will require you to resolve a conflict between the 2 histories. You might need to git push --force your branch on the remote to replace it. Make sure you're not erasing some changes made by your coworkers by doing so.
Changing only a piece of code's author
Commits can have multiple authors, but this concerns the whole commit, not sections of it. If you want a specific part of the code that was changed to have your name, you will have to create a new commit in which you change the code. You could for example make a commit in which you add 1 indentation to all the lines you want to be yours, and then a subsequent commit in which you revert your change.

will it take over whole commit ? I mentioned that I want to takeover only one file in a commit which had multiple files and that person shoud still be author present in annotations of all those other files

@SereneAtk a commit cannot have multiple authors based on which files are edited. If you really want to change the author of only a portion of the code, then you cannot do it by modifying the commit, you'll have to make a new commit in which you update the file you want your name on.

I edited my answer to provide a solution for only a piece of the code. I hope this helps
